# How to make app wait for service connection and authentication

Tags: android, service, connection

I need my app to wait on the loading screen so that a connection to the server may be made, and then enter the users saved credentials automatically using SaveSharedPreference and then move to the next page in MainActivity.

The connection is made through a service with a call in the onCreate blocks with:

`startService(new Intent(LoggingIn.this, MessagingService.class));`

and the users credentials are taken from SaveSharedPreference  and sent to the server within try/catch blocks as:

```
                result = imService.authenticateUser(
                        SaveSharedPreference
                                .getUserName(getApplicationContext()),
                        SaveSharedPreference
                                .getPassword(getApplicationContext()));
```

At present, the app simply boots up and then crashes. I tried using Thread.sleep(500) but that simply shuts the app down, and posts this error:

[image]

1. How can I get the functionality as outlined above and make my app wait for a connection to the server prior to sending `authenticateUser`
2. Wait for the successful logging in with `authenticateUser` before my app tries to launch `MainActivity`?

   ```
       setContentView(R.layout.loading_splash_page);

       // If already logged in, pull the information and send to server
       // to
       // auto log in

       Thread loginThread = new Thread() {
           private Handler handler = new Handler();

           @Override
           public void run() {
               // String result = null;

               try {

                   result = imService.authenticateUser(
                           SaveSharedPreference
                                   .getUserName(getApplicationContext()),
                           SaveSharedPreference
                                   .getPassword(getApplicationContext()));

               } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               if (result == null || result.equals(AUTHENTICATION_FAILED)) {
                   /*
                    * Authenticatin failed, inform the user
                    */
                   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           Toast.makeText(
                                   getApplicationContext(),
                                   R.string.make_sure_username_and_password_correct,
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                           // showDialog(MAKE_SURE_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD_CORRECT);
                       }
                   });

               } else {

                   /*
                    * if result not equal to authentication failed, result
                    * is equal to friend and group list of the user 0: is
                    * for friends, 1: is for groups
                    */
                   handler.post(new Runnable() {
                       public void run() {
                           Intent i = new Intent(LoggingIn.this,
                                   MainActivity.class);
                           startActivity(i);
                           LoggingIn.this.finish();

                       }
                   });

               }

           }
       };
       loginThread.start();
   ```

**ADDITION** The service merhods for imService:

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // established, giving us the service object we can use to
            // interact with the service. Because we have bound to a explicit
            // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
            // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
            imService = ((MessagingService.IMBinder) service).getService();

            if (imService.isUserAuthenticated() == true) {
                // Intent i = new Intent(LoggingIn.this, ListOfFriends.class);
                Intent i = new Intent(LoggingIn.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                LoggingIn.this.finish();
            }
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            // This is called when the connection with the service has been
            // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
            // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
            // see this happen.
            imService = null;
            Toast.makeText(LoggingIn.this, R.string.local_service_stopped,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

Comment: does it post any errors? if so post it

Comment: @Elltz I added the error, with what I have the app immediately crashes

Comment: what is imService object? just a brief info of it, are you using native libraries?

Comment: @Elltz I updated the question with the inService source methods

Comment: are you running on emulator or a samsung device?

Comment: Both but mostly android

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean Samsung

Comment: ok.. sir, do you get this error on the emulator too? because this is a samsung issue i guess,  so i will suggest you upgrade your current os version on your device, and it will work..it has nothing to do with codding structure..that's what i can say

Comment: @Elltz Sorry, it turned out that when I upgraded to Android 5.0, the ActionBar navigation methods were all deprecated. The InvocatonTargetException was just a wrapper for the NullPointer error on `NAVIGATION_LIST_MODE`